# Remove power options from menu in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, shutdown, menu, restart

I am setting up a Lab machine to be used by students, running Ubuntu 20.04.
I'd like to remove all power options from the menu, except Switch User and Logout.
I followed the instructions in [this](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/login-userlist-disable.html.en) manual, and added the line `disable-restart-buttons=true` to the file.
Is there something similar for the session?

EDIT: In Ubuntu 16.04 / Unity I managed the same by creating a file named `10_hide_user_list.gschema.override`, with the following lines: `[com.canonical.indicator.session]`, `suppress-restart-menuitem=true` and `suppress-shutdown-menuitem=true`. I then placed the file in the `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` directory.

Comment: have you tried gnome-shell extension BringoutSubmenu.. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2917/bring-out-submenu-of-power-offlogout-button/

Comment: are you looking to remove poweroff button from login screen t00??

Comment: I don't want to add extensions. The idea is to hide all but the Logout and Switch User menu items, to prevent users from restarting the machine.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, PRATAP!

Comment: any progress or workarounds you found?

Comment: Sorry to say  - no news, still looking for a way to prevent regular (=non-privileged) users from restarting / shutting down the machine...

Comment: Hey Penguin, just wondering if you managed to fix this. I have the same use case and was hoping to remove the power / networking options.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I don't visit this site too often. I found this [1] guide, haven't tried it recently, but I remember it worked for me before. I moved to Ubuntu 22.04, and I intend to try it there.[1] https://tipsonubuntu.com/2020/05/22/hide-power-off-ubuntu-20-04-login-screen/